# After updating from 9.2 to 9.3, my site breaks, but turning CSS/JS aggregation off fixes it. What can I change to make it so I can turn it back on?

Tags: 9, css-js-aggregation

After updating from 9.2 to 9.3, my site breaks. When I turn off CSS and JavaScript aggregation, it fixes my 9.3 versioned site. I would like to turn it on as that would speed up my site. Normally I find the issue is that the correct owner isn't in place or the permissions are off. My `sites/default/files` directory seems to have the correct permissions of 775 and the correct owner, being the server. The js and css directory in the files directory have the same permissions and owner as the files directory. I have also been clearing the cache. I have also run cron. Also, It is only an issue when I am logged in. Anonymous users wouldn't notice the difference.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand the issue. The only reason I got was that I need to have details added. What other details do I need to put in?

Comment: I don't think it is fair to keep getting marked down on this, while I am asking for help on what needs to be clarified or what added details are needed, and am getting no responses.

Comment: I had a very similar experience when upgrading from 8.9.20 to 9.2.10 aggregation broke site's theme. Files folder had the correct owner/group and perms. I noticed when I switched to the default, Bartik, theme everything was alright. So I knew it was something about my custom theme. I started deleting my theme's CSS files until I found the culprit file. I then started deleting lines of that file until I found the source. For me it was `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;600;700;800;900&display=swap');` apparently D9 doesn't like this.

Comment: So what I did was just copy the content of that url and pasted into my css file, aggregation problem solved.

Comment: Is it possible it's due to multiple semicolons in that URI? Otherwise if it's an issue while logged in, check logs and the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue! [This](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3195764) link talks about how previously, if a module required for example core/jquery.ui.dialog, Seven and Claro removed files that were breaking the layout. With this change, this override was removed, and broke my site. I read someone had this issue when using admin toolbar search, and this was my issue as well. I just uninstalled it and everything worked. While I will be taking jQuery out to prepare for D10, this will be fixed in D9 and needs review.